# Javascript: is there "Symbol.iterator" analogue for the object spread syntax - { ...obj }?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, getter, spread-syntax

There is a well known symbol: `Symbol.iterator`, that, when defined as a generator function property on an object, allows the object to be used in a `[...object]` syntax. So, you can do, eg., this:

```
const newArray = [ ...foo, ...object, ...bar ];
```

However, I couldn't find an analogue of that functionality, allowing this:

```
const newObject = { ...foo, ...object, ...etc };
```

or `Object.assign` with non-own properties.
Case in point: instances of ES6 classes with `get prop() / set prop()` accessors - they are defined on the `.prototype` property of the class constructor:

```
const C = class {
  #num = 42;
  #str = 'aaa';
  
  get num() { return this.#num; }
  set num(val) { /* validate new value */ this.#num = val; return true; }

  get str() { return this.#num; }
  set str(val) { /* validate new value */ this.#num = val; return true; }
}

const obj = new C();
```

Now `obj` has built-in validation for `obj.num = ...` and `obj.str = ...`. However, it cannot be used in `{...foo, ...obj}`, or in `Object.assign(foo, obj)`, because the accessors are on the prototype. Proxies can be spread, and property acces trapped for validation, but **one of my goals is to make accessing `obj.prop` as close in performance as possible to accessing plain object prop**. And look at this:

```
const p = new Proxy({ num: 0 }, {});

suite.add('instance with class-accessors', () => obj.num++);
suite.add('proxy', () => p.num++);
suite.run();

instance with class-accessors x ***235***,971,841 ops/sec ±0.20% (86 runs sampled)
proxy x ***1***,014,238 ops/sec ±1.91% (84 runs sampled)
```

**Two orders of magnitude slower!** So, is there a way to allow `{ ...obj }` / `Object.assign` for instances with prototype based getters?

I did experiment, just in case, with defining `*[Symbol.iterator]() {...}` in the class, yielding `Object.entries`-style pairs of `[prop, val]`, didn't work. Didn't find anything useful on MDN's "Well known symbols". Expected to find something like, eg., `Symbol.entries`, something that can control spread/assign and make instances with getters usage transparent.

Comment: I think it's essentially equivalent to looping over `Object.entries(source)`

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. Object literal spread syntax just picks all enumerable own properties, that's it.

The common workaround is to define a getter method to serialise an object that can be spread as you want, often also used for JSON conversion:

```js
class C {
  #num = 42;
  #str = 'aaa';
  get num() { return this.#num; }
  get str() { return this.#num; }
  // …
  toJSON() {
    return {num: this.#num, str: this.#str};
  }
}

const object = new C();

const newObject = { x: 1, ...object.toJSON(), y: 2 };
console.log(newObject);
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```